# create Index on Loc in mongoDB

Tags: mongodb

## Problem

I want to create index on location with lat lng key value. 
I have done so far is that

> db.collection.createIndex( { "loc" : "2dsphere" } )

How can I achieve this

```
{
    "_id" : "14613879205654654648572",        
    "birthDate" : ISODate("1992-07-17T00:00:00.000Z"),
    "loc" : {
        "lat" : 31.5200788,
        "lng" : 74.3236112
    }
}
```

Comment: `db.collection.createIndex( {  "loc": "2dsphere" } )`. What's the problem? Drop anything you created prior to that because it would be wrong, and there are issues with multiple geo indexes on a collection.

Comment: Really you should ["Read the fine manual"](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/2dsphere/#dsphere-indexed-field-restrictions) which tells you all about what formats you can and should use for storage.